# The set of the roots of all polynomials in one variable with integer coefficients

Tags: soft-question

Is the following set countable::

The set of the  roots of all polynomials in one variable  with integer coefficients.

Please show the mapping between $N$ and the above set if the set is so

I think it is not countable since for each positive integer we can get uncountably many polynomials of that degree

Comment: Note that your last statement is false because you can indeed go through each polynomial one by one.. at step $k$ list all those with degree $k$ and coefficients with absolute value no larger than $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a clause: the set of roots of all *nonzero* polynomials in one variable, with integer coefficients.

Those numbers are the *algebraic numbers*. Denote by $X$ the set of algebraic integers. Then we have an injective map $\mathbb{N}\to X$, because $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a root of the polynomial $x-n$.

For each nonzero polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients, denote by $R(f)$ the set of (complex) roots of $f$. Each $R(f)$ is finite, so $X$ is the union of a countable family of finite sets, hence it is at most countable.

Why is the family countable? Because the set of polynomials with integer coefficients is countable.

*Proof.* It is sufficient to show that the set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$ is countable (why?).

For a polynomial $f$ with natural coefficients, define its *weight* $w(f)$ as the sum of its coefficients (which is just $f(1)$). Then, for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a finite number of polynomials with weight $m$. So the set of polynomials is a countable union of finite sets, hence it is countable.

Comment: If the polynomials are not unitary, $X$ is the set of `algebraic numbers`, not integers.

Comment: @Bernard You're right. I'll fix it.